# How to disable PayPal Express Checkout's requirement for city parameter?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

How can I tell Paypal Express Checkout that I don't require any address information to process my order?  I'm sending the NOSHIPPING=1 parameter in my request, but once I submit the order to the paypal sandbox, confirm my payment, and return back to my webpage, I get the following errro message:

```
L_ERRORCODE0 -> 10728
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 -> Shipping Address City Empty
L_LONGMESSAGE0 -> The field Shipping Address City is required
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOSHIPPING=1` in SetExpressCheckout is fine, but it will still validate the addess if you send any sort of address parameter.
To turn this off, ensure you don't send any `SHIPTOxxxxx` parameters at all (such as SHIPTONAME, SHIPTOSTREET, etc.) OR that you don't send `ADDROVERRIDE=1`

Comment: @PayPal_Robert I was trying to do something like this only, but if I don't send the shipping info now, when would I need to send PP this info  ?

Comment: I've updated my answer - are you sending ADDROVERRIDE=1?